# What's difference between 国籍 and 民族?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I'm revising vocabulary for HSK4 and I found many words with similar meanings. A pair I found today was: 国籍 and 民族. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- 国籍 = nationality (as based on what nation you are from)
- 民族 = ethnic group

For the majority of Chinese people their:

- 国籍 = 中国 (Chinese)
- 民族 = 汉 (Han)

Comment: As a matter of interest, how would 华人 be classified？

Comment: @WayneCheah 族裔?

Comment: Thanks. I suppose so.

Answer (score 1):

["Nationality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationality):

> ... establish[es a] person as a subject, a national, of a sovereign state

[A "nation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation):

> ... is a stable community of humans formed on the basis of a common language, territory, history, ethnicity, or psychological make-up manifested in a common culture

I think this is where the confusion comes in between the two Chinese terms.

- 民族 is sometimes confusingly translated as "nationality" in the sense of belonging to a *nation* in that broader sense (though the usual English word for this is actual "ethnicity" or "ethnic group").
- 国籍 is what's usually referred to as "nationality" in English - being a national of a country or territory. This has legal meaning and would be written on passports and other official documents.

Answer (score 0):

国籍（nationality）指的是哪国人，对于中国人国籍是中国；民族（nation）指的是你所在的民族，比如中国有56个民族，其中汉族是人数最多的民族.

Comment: 你好，感谢你的回答！根据本论坛的社区规则和习惯，希望问题和答案两者的语言能够保持一致，以确保提问者以及其他中文水平为初级的朋友们都能看懂。这次提问语言以英文为主，请你尽量用英文回答。如果你的英文水平不足，我们可以帮你修改